# Term to describe the two ways of labeling the vertices of a tetrahedron.

Tags: terminology

I can label the vertices of a tetrahedron in two different ways as are depicted in the following picture. How to differentiate the two? Is there a term or a mathematical statement? I suspect that it is "*chirality*" but I'm not sure.

In this context, the order of labeling is significant. In the picture, $A$ is between plane $BCD$ and the eyes of a typical StackExchange user.

[image: Different labeling of tetrahedron vertices]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you order the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, then [there's some evidence](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/index.html#title0) that **(b)** could be called "positively oriented" (or perhaps "right chiral") and **(a)** could be called "negatively oriented" (or perhaps "left chiral"). The reason is an analogy to the [positive orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_%28vector_space%29) of the standard coordinate system: we should take the tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$ to have positive orientation.