# Opposite Orientation

Tags: geometry, 3d

This is my first time on MSE!

I came because I had a quick question about a problem that my geometry teacher assigned me.

In the wording of the problem, it says "these two square pyramids are labeled with opposite orientation." What does that mean? Is it something similar to this: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624029/term-to-describe-the-two-ways-of-labeling-the-vertices-of-a-tetrahedron)?

Comment: I don't think we can really answer that without the full text of the problem.

Comment: "There are two regular square pyramids with side length $2$: $ABCDE$ and $FGHIJ$. Sketch them out given that these two square pyramids are labeled with opposite orientation."